# Browser back button and browser close button javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there a way to identify browser back button and browser close button event differently?

Comment: Do you want to identify that they have been clicked? ie the event has happened?

Comment: yes, but where? you have some code to show us?

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish them? They both leave the current page.

Comment: Yes, need to identify that they have been clicked. Because I have to logout the user from application if he closes the browser but not on clicking back button and also I cant disable the back button.